# how to tweet url in twitter in iphone

Tags: android, iphone, objective-c, twitter, tweets

When I reached the maximum character limit, I can't tweet my url.

Up to 140 character it works fine.

From  130 characters, when I started to write the link, I get the message

`Link will appear shortened`

but I can't click on `Tweet Button`. Instead, I get a message at the top of screen

`Your Tweet was over 140 characters. You'll have to be more clever`

I have already check [this link](https://support.twitter.com/articles/78124-how-to-shorten-links-urls)

Thanks

Comment: Are you experiencing this in your own code?

Comment: I guess that twitter will shorten your link using `t.co` but even the shortened version is longer than 10 characters. You should write shorter tweets

Comment: @rckoenes can we write url after 130 text

Answer (score 4):

```
- (void)postOnTwitter
{
    //  You can take url with any length....
    NSString *shareLink = @"https://www.google.co.in/"
    //   text should be under 140 character size
    //   TEXT MUST BE END WITH "." dot.
    NSString *text = @"Heyyy... I am sharing Url with any length."
    NSString *tweetStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",text, shareLink];

    NSMutableDictionary *message = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tweetStr,@"status", nil];

    NSURLRequest* request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" parameters:message error:nil];

    [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient] sendTwitterRequest:request     completion:^(NSURLResponse* response, NSData* data, NSError* error){
        if(!error)
        {
            //    Post successfully 
        }
        else if(error)
       {
            //   Check for Error
        }
    }];
}
```